# Do Tensors "act" on each other?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I know that , 
Derivatives are a kind of Linear Transformation. (Because they are a linear operator) 
Linear Transformation Are a kind of Tensor.
So Are Derivatives just another kind of tensor?
If that is , it seems like taking the Derivatives of Tensor Is like a Tensor "Acting" on another tensor.
So , even is Tensors "act on each other , do they form some sort of a Group ?

Another example , Linear Transformation can act on vectors.They are both tensors , so it again seems like One Tensor [the linear transformation] is acting on another tensor [the vector]. Am I thinking something wrong over here?

Comment: Tensor fields on a manifold $M$ are $C^\infty(M)$-linear, while derivatives are $\Bbb R$-linear, not $C^\infty(M)$-linear (due to the Leibniz rule). It's not the same thing.

Comment: Actions are always defined in relations to some algebraic entity interacting with a set via some operation that respects the algebraic structure. This means you'll need to clearly define the algebraic structure of the tensors and how they operate on the other tensors to ensure that it is an action. Since a vector and a matrix can both be considered tensors a simple action involving tensors can be seen if we consider $A$ a matrix and $x$ a vector so that the product $Ax$ is defined. Then the matrix acts on the vector, or vice versa with respect to the vector space structure of both.

Comment: Yes, derivatives are a tensor (though not, as Ivo Terek points out, a tensor *field*), but only because "Tensor" is a very big term that applies quite widely. With the right definitions, I can also make your nose a tensor, if you'd like (simplest: take $\Bbb R$ with normal operations, but using your nose to act as "$1$"). Just because one thing that can be fit to the definition of "tensor" acts on something else that can be fit to the definition of "tensor" does not mean every tensor acts on every other tensor.